# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - React Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I add the quantity of product on the product page everything works properly and it transfers me to the cart where it shows how much quantity I have chosen.

When I try to update the product quantity in the cart, it throws me an error.

**My CartScreen Code:**

```
function CartScreen(props) {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;
  const productId = props.match.params.id;
  const qty = props.location.search
    ? Number(props.location.search.split("=")[1])
    : 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const removeFromCartHandler = (productId) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(productId));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div className="cart">
        <div className="cart-list">
          <ul className="cart-list-container">
            <li>
              <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
              <div>Price</div>
            </li>
            {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
              <div>Cart is empty</div>
            ) : (
              cartItems.map((item) => (
                <li>
                  <div className="cart-image">
                    <img src={item.image} alt="product" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="cart-name">
                    <div>
                      <Link to={"/product/" + item.product}>{item.name}</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      Qty:
                      <select
                        value={item.qty}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          dispatch(addToCart(item.product, e.target.value))
                        }
                      >
                        {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                          <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                            {x + 1}
                          </option>
                        ))}
                      </select>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="button"
                        onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="cart-price">${item.price}</div>
                </li>
              ))
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="cart-action">
          <h3>
            Subtotal ( {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty, 0)} items) : ${" "}
            {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.qty, 0)}
          </h3>
          <button
            className="button primary full-width"
            disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
          >
            Proceed to Checkout
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**My CartAction Code:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM } from "../constants/cartConstants";

const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products/" + productId);
    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload: {
        product: data._id,
        name: data.name,
        image: data.image,
        price: data.price,
        countInStock: data.countInStock,
        qty,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {}
};
const removeFromCart = (productId) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM, payload: productId });
};
export { addToCart, removeFromCart };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CartScreen component what does it say in the console for `cartItems` ?

Just check your code with `useSelector` hook and what is it returning.

it must return an object with `cartitems` key with value as an array.

You could even do this to avoid the error and to define a default value and fix the return object value in `useSelector` as well.

```js
const { cartItems = [] } = cart;
```

Comment: When I try to add const { cartItems = [] } = cart; everything from my cart are delete.
If you can check my github where is my project:

https://github.com/haris-hthc/ed-vision-shop

Comment: Observations:
1. Rename folder `Screens` to `screens` as you are importing from `screens`.
2. Check your `addToCart` function REST API response. It worked for me with dummy data as I don't have access to your REST API.

Suggestion:
Add to cart in the product page itself and then redirect to cart page if needed because adding from url params might cause adding of the item multiple times on refresh.